# Run server from a react website

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Im creating a react website at one point of the website I want to run a server normally I run this server from the command line with `node server.js` but I want to run this with a button click on my website. Both files are in the same filestructure.

So how can I run the server from the webpage?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @AndréSnedeKock how do I run the server from the webpage

Comment: I presuming you want to run an additional server. Make an endpoint that runs `node server.js`.

Comment: It is smarter to run `node server.js` in the command line.

Comment: @dasdachs what is the best way to do that because I want to not run it as soon as the website loads. It must load when the button is clicked.

Comment: @DamienGold I know but I want to run it trough the button thats just how to system works :)

Comment: @RickGrendel You need to bind a listener to button click, then when the button is clicked make a request to the end point that starts server say, `website.com/start/my/server` the backend handling the end-point request should start the server using the system call method of the language which is usually `exec()` in most languages.

Comment: I can't understand the point of doing this. You'd likely create a security weakness in your infrastructure. Why not look at serverless architecture? There are solutions from [Google](https://cloud.google.com/serverless/), [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/serverless/) and [Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/), amongst others.